# PHP Serial Port Access

Tags: php, serial-port, gsm

I am trying to implement this code below, I have a wavecom gsm modem connected to COM6 https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFH8l.jpg it works on 3rd party sms gateway software but it is very expensive.

I am getting these errors

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Unable to setup COM port, check it is correct' in C:\wamp\www\sms\index.php on line 53
>   ( ! ) Exception: Unable to setup COM port, check it is correct in C:\wamp\www\sms\index.php on line 53

What do i need to do to make this work?

```
<?php

//SMS via GSM Modem - A PHP class to send SMS messages via a GSM modem attached to the computers serial port.

//Windows only (tested on XP with PHP 5.2.6)
//Tested with the EZ863 (Telit GE863) GSM modem
//Requires that PHP has permission to access "COM" system device, and system "mode" command

error_reporting(E_ALL);

//Example

$gsm_send_sms = new gsm_send_sms();
$gsm_send_sms->debug = false;
$gsm_send_sms->port = 'COM6';
$gsm_send_sms->baud = 9600;
$gsm_send_sms->init();

$status = $gsm_send_sms->send('+642102844012', 'testing 123');
if ($status) {
    echo "Message sent\n";
} else {
    echo "Message not sent\n";
}

$gsm_send_sms->close();







//Send SMS via serial SMS modem
class gsm_send_sms {

    public $port = 'COM6';
    public $baud = 9600;

    public $debug = false;

    private $fp;
    private $buffer;

    //Setup COM port
    public function init() {

        $this->debugmsg("Setting up port: \"{$this->port} @ \"{$this->baud}\" baud");

        exec("MODE {$this->port}: BAUD={$this->baud} PARITY=N DATA=8 STOP=1", $output, $retval);

        if ($retval != 0) {
            throw new Exception('Unable to setup COM port, check it is correct');
        }

        $this->debugmsg(implode("\n", $output));

        $this->debugmsg("Opening port");

        //Open COM port
        $this->fp = fopen($this->port . ':', 'r+');

        //Check port opened
        if (!$this->fp) {
            throw new Exception("Unable to open port \"{$this->port}\"");
        }

        $this->debugmsg("Port opened");
        $this->debugmsg("Checking for responce from modem");

        //Check modem connected
        fputs($this->fp, "AT\r");

        //Wait for ok
        $status = $this->wait_reply("OK\r\n", 5);

        if (!$status) {
            throw new Exception('Did not receive responce from modem');
        }

        $this->debugmsg('Modem connected');

        //Set modem to SMS text mode
        $this->debugmsg('Setting text mode');
        fputs($this->fp, "AT+CMGF=1\r");

        $status = $this->wait_reply("OK\r\n", 5);

        if (!$status) {
            throw new Exception('Unable to set text mode');
        }

        $this->debugmsg('Text mode set');

    }

    //Wait for reply from modem
    private function wait_reply($expected_result, $timeout) {

        $this->debugmsg("Waiting {$timeout} seconds for expected result");

        //Clear buffer
        $this->buffer = '';

        //Set timeout
        $timeoutat = time() + $timeout;

        //Loop until timeout reached (or expected result found)
        do {

            $this->debugmsg('Now: ' . time() . ", Timeout at: {$timeoutat}");

            $buffer = fread($this->fp, 1024);
            $this->buffer .= $buffer;

            usleep(200000);//0.2 sec

            $this->debugmsg("Received: {$buffer}");

            //Check if received expected responce
            if (preg_match('/'.preg_quote($expected_result, '/').'$/', $this->buffer)) {
                $this->debugmsg('Found match');
                return true;
                //break;
            } else if (preg_match('/\+CMS ERROR\:\ \d{1,3}\r\n$/', $this->buffer)) {
                return false;
            }

        } while ($timeoutat > time());

        $this->debugmsg('Timed out');

        return false;

    }

    //Print debug messages
    private function debugmsg($message) {

        if ($this->debug == true) {
            $message = preg_replace("%[^\040-\176\n\t]%", '', $message);
            echo $message . "\n";
        }

    }

    //Close port
    public function close() {

        $this->debugmsg('Closing port');

        fclose($this->fp);

    }

    //Send message
    public function send($tel, $message) {

        //Filter tel
        $tel = preg_replace("%[^0-9\+]%", '', $tel);

        //Filter message text
        $message = preg_replace("%[^\040-\176\r\n\t]%", '', $message);

        $this->debugmsg("Sending message \"{$message}\" to \"{$tel}\"");

        //Start sending of message
        fputs($this->fp, "AT+CMGS=\"{$tel}\"\r");

        //Wait for confirmation
        $status = $this->wait_reply("\r\n> ", 5);

        if (!$status) {
            //throw new Exception('Did not receive confirmation from modem');
            $this->debugmsg('Did not receive confirmation from modem');
            return false;
        }

        //Send message text
        fputs($this->fp, $message);

        //Send message finished indicator
        fputs($this->fp, chr(26));

        //Wait for confirmation
        $status = $this->wait_reply("OK\r\n", 180);

        if (!$status) {
            //throw new Exception('Did not receive confirmation of messgage sent');
            $this->debugmsg('Did not receive confirmation of messgage sent');
            return false;
        }

        $this->debugmsg("Message sent");

        return true;

    }

}

?>
```

Comment: Hello, and welcome to stack overflow. Please try to trim your code down to the area where you think the problem lies; this is too much code to look through. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this below code hope it helps,
Note : uses php_serial.class.php

Code :

```
<?php


require("php_serial.class.php");


$serial = new phpSerial;

// First we must specify the device. This works on both linux and windows (if
// your linux serial device is /dev/ttyS0 for COM1, etc)
$serial->deviceSet("/dev/ttyS0");

// We can change the baud rate, parity, length, stop bits, flow control
$serial->confBaudRate(9600);
$serial->confParity("none");
$serial->confCharacterLength(8);
$serial->confStopBits(1);
$serial->confFlowControl("none");

// Then we need to open it
$serial->deviceOpen();  



// To write into
$serial->sendMessage("AT+CMGF=1\n\r"); 
$serial->sendMessage("AT+cmgs=\"+912709345x23\"\n\r");
$serial->sendMessage("Hi, This is the sms that I sent to you using PHP script with serial Port communication with my phone as serial device!! GN - VKSALIAN \n\r");
$serial->sendMessage(chr(26));

//wait for modem to send message
sleep(7);


// Or to read from
$read = $serial->readPort();
echo $read;
// If you want to change the configuration, the device must be closed
$serial->deviceClose();

?>
```